# How to search tweets based on tweet-id in Python?

Tags: python, twitter

I got a dataset that only has tweet-ids like "1300747127350423552", can I search tweets from these in Python?
I tried this code:

> tweet = api.statuses_lookup(['1300747127350423552'])
> a1[0].text

but it didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work - what was the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I can search for that ID and get results using TWEEPY.   I will refrain from posting results due to privacy concerns.

```
import tweepy
   
def searchtweet():
    twitter_auth_keys = {
        "consumer_key": "yours goes here",
        "consumer_secret": "yours goes here",
        "access_token": "yours goes here",
        "access_token_secret": "yours goes here"
    }
  

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
    )
    auth.set_access_token(
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
    )

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    print(api.statuses_lookup(["INSERT YOUR SEARCH TWEET ID HERE"]))

def main():
    searchtweet()
```